# Drupal wkhtmltopdf font error

Tags: html, css, fonts, drupal-7, wkhtmltopdf

[image: image showing the error] I am using the wkhtmltopdf library within Drupal. The issue I am experiencing is how the fonts are displaying in a PDF view. Each time I convert a HTML page to PDF. The PDF text (p tags) are displayed in the wingdings font.

In the image I've attached above you will see a PDF view showing the p tags in wingdings and the h1 and h2 text is displayed in droid serif.

Having played around with the CSS, I have strangely managed to work out that if I change the font weight to 600 and over the font displays in the PDF view. This is why the h1 + h2 text is being displayed.

My CSS is pretty basic

```
body, p, p a {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", "Georgia", serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the fonts being used, were not being recognized in the PDF view. So I researched into why the font styles were displaying in the converted PDF’s. I decided to follow this [fix][1 font not working in wkhtmltopdf].

In this solution it mentions encoding fonts using Base64 and then using it with the CSS. I tried various methods for encoding the font types to Base64 and adding them within the style sheet. All my attempts at this seemed to fail.

So I gave up on that and I decided to look into using Google Fonts. I went over to the Google Fonts page. Reading through how it works, I worked out the following css rule;

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Georgia:400);
  body, p, p a {
  font-family: "Droid Serif", "Georgia", serif;
  }
```

The CSS rule snippet give's me my desired outcome. The font appears to have not been compromised and it looks exactly like the original webpage. Which is what I was looking for :>)

Answer (score 0):

When we had this on just one of our Centos servers it was due to missing fonts. Curiously bold text, large text was just fine, it was ordinary text which was wingdinged !!

```
yum install dejavu-sans-fonts
```

What actually solved all our font problems was:-

```
yum install ghostscript
```